# jquery checkboxlist particular element

Tags: asp.net, jquery

In ASP.NET CheckBoxList is there any way to determine of a particular checkbox is checked using jquery? I need to know if "All" is checked for example, either by value or label text.

```
      <asp:CheckBoxList ID ="ToyotaModels" runat="server">    
               <asp:ListItem Value = "0">Corolla<asp:ListItem>
               <asp:ListItem Value = "1">Matrix<asp:ListItem>
               <asp:ListItem Value = "2">Tundra</asp:ListItem>
               <asp:ListItem Value = "3">Prius</asp:ListItem>
               <asp:ListItem Value = "4">All</asp:ListItem>
      </asp:CheckBoxList>
```

Comment: We need to know the HTML output of the CheckBoxList.

Comment: i'm not sure how it works with asp, but in jQuery you can check if an element is checked by calling is(":checked") as in $("li[value='4']").is(":checked")

Comment: One day, I will understand what those bizarre tags mean, and why they are used.

Comment: @karim79, be careful, man, there are dark things lurking in the deeps, of which men were not meant to know.

Comment: @karim79 - you probably know this(or not), but basically, what Jer implies is what does the "real" markup presented at the browser look like - the runat="server" means it gets "translated" into HTML elements by the server, then presented.  In this case, a list of checkboxes <input type="checkbox"> and some more label stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get the checked checkboxes on a click:

```
$('input:checked').click().each(function() {
            //process the checkbox stuff here..
 });
```

EDIT: based on comment

```
 function processChecks()
{   
    $('input:checked').each(function() 
    {
     alert($(this).val();
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. This is not a click event handler though. I was thinking to do something like this, in the 'input:checked' loop find out if particular element is one of the checked. Was just wondering if there is more elegant way of doing it, perhaps in a single selector?

Comment: so probably just take out the .click() from that (inside whatever you have that instigates the behavior you need) 
$('input:checked').each(function() { 
            //process the checkbox stuff here.. 
 });

Comment: Thanks. This worked: $('#<%= ToyotaModels.ClientID %> input:checked').each(function().

Answer (score 1):

You have to look at the HTML generated by ASP.NET's CheckboxList. The ID of the container for the inputs which are the check boxes is going to look like this in javascript:

```
<%= ToyotaModels.ClientID %>
```

Each checkbox input has `_X` appended to the ID where X is the numeric checkbox. So to find whether the first item (Corolla) is checked you can do this:

```
$('<%= "#" +  ToyotaModels.ClientID + "_0" %>').is(":checked")
```

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery you have .is(":checked") function that should do the trick.